# Redirect to a specified port when using https

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, htaccess

I have an internal domain: cloud.flint.lo

I would like to achieve the following:

```
If URL=http://cloud.filnt.lo
   Redirect to: https://cloud.flint.lo:5001/sub
If URL=https://cloud.flint.lo
   Redirect to: https://cloud.flint.lo:5001
```

I wrote this in .htaccess, but only the first scenario works:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^5001$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}:5001/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$                                                                                                                                                
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}:5001/sub [L,R=301]
```

I also tried to use "REQUEST_URI" to match the 5001 port but didn't work either.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on                                                                                                                                                     
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\:5001
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}:5001/sub [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `mod_rewrite` seems a bit like overkill here. You may want to consider using [Redirect](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/avoid.html) (part of `mod_alias`) instead.

*ex. Virtual Host 1 (HTTP)*

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName cloud.flint.lo

Redirect permanent / https://cloud.flint.lo:5001/sub/

</VirtualHost>
```

*ex. Virtual Host 2 (HTTPS)*

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

ServerName cloud.flint.lo

Redirect permanent / https://cloud.flint.lo:5001/

</VirtualHost>
```

**Notes**

- There may be some additional standard SSL statements required in any HTTPS virtual host (but this depends entirely on your configuration).
- The example `Redirect` statements can of course simply be part of your primary Apache configuration files (particularly `httpd-ssl.conf` for the second example).
- `Redirect` is used in place of `DocumentRoot`.

**Using Apache mod_rewrite**

Alternately, if you feel Apache `mod_rewrite` is more desirable for your use case, you can try the following:

*ex. HTTP Host*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$                                                                                                                                                
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ {HTTP_HOST}:5001/sub$1 [L,R=301]
```

*ex. HTTPS Host*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}:5001$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: The second example didn't work either. And I am still prefer the mod_rewrite method because the website may move to webhosting in the future.

Comment: I have added mod_rewrite options. However, please note that all the suggestion given should work. If the added examples do not work for you, there may be additional issues you are facing.

Comment: You may also wish give more specifics about the problem(s) you are encountering.

Comment: Both of the methods works now. Thank you @Anaksunaman!

Comment: Glad to hear it. You're welcome. =)